# Why is there a funny "block" in my GridView CommandField?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

On my Gridview, I have a CommandField which I use WingDings 2 characters rather than text. The problem is that when the gridview is displayed, there appears to be a funny black "block" inbetween the Edit (Pen) and Delete (Trash Can) and I don't know how to get rid of it.

Here's the markup

```
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link"
    ShowDeleteButton="true" DeleteText="&#x33;"
    ShowEditButton="true" EditText="&#x21"
    UpdateText="&#x50;"
    CancelText="&#x4F;">
    <ItemStyle CssClass="View3 CommandField" />
</asp:CommandField>
```

Here's the CSSClass

```
#DisruptionDataGrid .CommandField {
    Width: 100px;
    font-family: 'WingDings 2';
    color: Black;
    Font-Size: 16px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: that looks like an individual element there. there could be a number of reasons. have you inspected the element within your browser?

Comment: Well, looking at "View Source" it seems to be putting a &nbsp; between the two links

Comment: <td class="View3 CommandField"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gv&#39;,&#39;Edit$0&#39;)">&#x21</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gv&#39;,&#39;Delete$0&#39;)">3</a></td>

Answer (score 0):

OK... I've now resolved this...

I had the CSSClass assigned to the ITEMSTYLE of the command field so that was applying the font to the entire cell.

I refactored and put the CSSClass on the CONTROLSYTLE instead and now the "block" has gone.

```
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link"
    ShowDeleteButton="true" DeleteText="&#x33;"
    ShowEditButton="true" EditText="&#x21"
    UpdateText="&#x50;"
    CancelText="&#x4F;">

    <ControlStyle CssClass="CommandField"/>

    <ItemStyle CssClass="View3" />
</asp:CommandField>
```